Search tag between tags after splited string
I'm using SQLite and PDO for run some SQL commands.
table fields and data:
ID      title       tag           pcode
----------------------------------------
1       title1      aa,bb,cc,dd   a100
2       title2      cc,ee,dd,ba   b250
3       title3      dd,ff,gr,ax   br10
4       title4      cc,dd,aa,fx   q200
5       title5      xx,ad,fr,aa   ar50

I just want separate current field tag value with , character and then search between all tags exists in tag field except current pcode value
As an example: I want to find all tags like as cc or dd or aa or fx with current record and when current pcode is q200 with tag content cc,dd,aa,fx except pcode q200
I did try it with this:
select title,pcode from tblproduct WHERE (tag like '%cc%') and (pcode <> 'q200')
It works, but how can I change it to find all values from current tag, meaning:
Search cc and then search dd and then search aa and then search fx value inside all tags in table except pcode with q200

I realise it is not what you are asking for, but did you consider changing the structure so that this concatenation thing is not needed?

Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?

@Yunnosch i can't change table fields, any idea for get result about what i want?

thanks for all helps, temporary i used this way just with change gr300 to any product code as i want or change to variable,good luck.
WITH RECURSIVE ctags AS (
SELECT
    id,
    producttitle,
    tags,
    productcode,
    instr(tags, ',') AS pos,
    substr(tags, 1, instr(tags, ',') - 1) AS tag_value,
    substr(tags, instr(tags, ',') + 1) AS rest
FROM
    tblproduct
WHERE
    productcode = 'gr300'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    id,
    producttitle,
    tags,
    productcode,
    instr(rest, ',') AS pos,
    CASE
        WHEN instr(rest, ',') = 0 THEN rest
        ELSE substr(rest, 1, instr(rest, ',') - 1)
    END AS tag_value,
    CASE
        WHEN instr(rest, ',') = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE substr(rest, instr(rest, ',') + 1)
    END AS rest
FROM
    ctags
WHERE
    rest <> ''
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id,
    p.producttitle,
    p.productcode,
    p.tags
FROM
    tblproduct p
JOIN
    ctags t ON p.tags LIKE '%' || t.tag_value || '%' AND p.productcode <> 'gr300'


You can probably utilise an IN clause in conjunction with a recursive CTE that splits the tags into individual tags e.g.:-
WITH
    /* CTE (Common Table Expression) 
        splits the tag into individual tags with an output row per each tag/tblproduct row combination
    */
    cte_split AS (
        /* Initial row (per row in tblproduct) */
        SELECT 
            id,title,pcode, /* only really need the id column*/
            '' AS current_tag, 
            tag||',' AS remaining_tags /* NOTE the addition of the trailing comma so instr works on last tag*/ 
        FROM tblproduct
        /* recursively strip of the current tag and prepare the remaining_tags for the next */
        UNION ALL select 
            id,title,pcode, /* copy the original columns */
            /* get the currrent tag*/
            substr(remaining_tags,1,instr(remaining_tags,',')-1) AS current_tag,
            substr(remaining_tags,instr(remaining_tags,',')+1) AS remaining_tags
        FROM cte_split
        WHERE length(remaining_tags) > 0 /* this should determine when the recursion stops */
        LIMIT 100 /* just in case limit the number of recursions */
    )
/* Now the cte can be used for an IN */
/* !!!!NOTE!!!! IN is an exact so LIKE not usable */
SELECT * FROM tblproduct 
WHERE pcode <> 'q200' 
AND 'cc' IN (SELECT (current_tag) FROM cte_split WHERE cte_split.id = tblproduct.id AND length(current_tag) > 0)
OR 'aa' IN (SELECT (current_tag) FROM cte_split WHERE cte_split.id = tblproduct.id AND length(current_tag) > 0)
OR 'fx' IN (SELECT (current_tag) FROM cte_split WHERE cte_split.id = tblproduct.id AND length(current_tag) > 0)

;
Results in :-


Note the final SELECT with WHERE pcode <> 'q200' and the 'cc' IN (SELECT ....
the LIMIT 100 may need to be changed to a more suitable value (or could even be removed)
note that IN is an exact match so wild characters cannot be used.

The CTE ( execution temporary table) has the following data:-


As can be seen as tags are extracted into the current_tag column,  the remaining_tags column

note how the initial empty current_tag per tblproduct row is excluded within the IN clause.



Demo SQL
The following SQL was used to generate the above answer:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblproduct;

/*
ID      title       tag           pcode
----------------------------------------
1       title1      aa,bb,cc,dd   a100
2       title2      cc,ee,dd,ba   b250
3       title3      dd,ff,gr,ax   br10
4       title4      cc,dd,aa,fx   q200
5       title5      xx,ad,fr,aa   ar50
*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblproduct (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, tag TEXT, pcode TEXT);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tblproduct VALUES
    (1,'title1','aa,bb,cc,dd','a100'),
    (2,'title2','cc,ee,dd,ba','b250'),
    (3,'title3','dd,ff,gr,ax','br10'),
    (4,'title4','cc,dd,aa,fx','q200'),
    (5,'title5','xx,ad,fr,aa','ar50')
;

/* DEMO of the CTE table (i.e. just drives )*/
WITH
    /* CTE (Common Table Expression) 
        splits the tag into individual tags with an output row per each tag/tblproduct row combination
    */
    cte_split AS (
        /* Initial row (per row in tblproduct) */
        SELECT 
            id,title,pcode, /* only really need the id column*/
            '' AS current_tag, 
            tag||',' AS remaining_tags /* NOTE the addition of the trailing comma so instr works on last tag*/ 
        FROM tblproduct
        /* recursively strip of the current tag and prepare the remaining_tags for the next */
        UNION ALL select 
            id,title,pcode, /* copy the original columns */
            /* get the currrent tag*/
            substr(remaining_tags,1,instr(remaining_tags,',')-1) AS current_tag,
            substr(remaining_tags,instr(remaining_tags,',')+1) AS remaining_tags
        FROM cte_split
        WHERE length(remaining_tags) > 0 /* this should determing when the recursion stops */
        LIMIT 100 /* just in case limit the number of recursions */
    )
/* Now the cte can be used for an IN */
/* !!!!NOTE!!!! IN is an exact so LIKE not usable */
SELECT * FROM cte_split
;
WITH
    /* CTE (Common Table Expression) 
        splits the tag into individual tags with an output row per each tag/tblproduct row combination
    */
    cte_split AS (
        /* Initial row (per row in tblproduct) */
        SELECT 
            id,title,pcode, /* only really need the id column*/
            '' AS current_tag, 
            tag||',' AS remaining_tags /* NOTE the addition of the trailing comma so instr works on last tag*/ 
        FROM tblproduct
        /* recursively strip of the current tag and prepare the remaining_tags for the next */
        UNION ALL select 
            id,title,pcode, /* copy the original columns */
            /* get the currrent tag*/
            substr(remaining_tags,1,instr(remaining_tags,',')-1) AS current_tag,
            substr(remaining_tags,instr(remaining_tags,',')+1) AS remaining_tags
        FROM cte_split
        WHERE length(remaining_tags) > 0 /* this should determing when the recursion stops */
        LIMIT 100 /* just in case limit the number of recursions */
    )
/* Now the cte can be used for an IN */
/* !!!!NOTE!!!! IN is an exact so LIKE not usable */
SELECT * FROM tblproduct 
WHERE pcode <> 'q200' 
AND 'cc' IN (SELECT (current_tag) FROM cte_split WHERE cte_split.id = tblproduct.id AND length(current_tag) > 0)
OR 'aa' IN (SELECT (current_tag) FROM cte_split WHERE cte_split.id = tblproduct.id AND length(current_tag) > 0)
OR 'fx' IN (SELECT (current_tag) FROM cte_split WHERE cte_split.id = tblproduct.id AND length(current_tag) > 0)
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblproduct;


Thanks for answer, as i can see the cte_split store all tags in separate records.i have two questions:

base on cte_split as i exampled about current pcode is q200 so means maybe current record will be another value with different tag value and different tag count, for example maybe current record will be about b250 with cc,ee,dd,ba,... and etc.so how can i make it dynamic, if i want use like as SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE pcode <> 'q200' AND 'cc' IN (SELECT (current_tag) ... so i need to change where and IN conditions every time


there is any way to i can make it dynamic based on current record tag value except current record pcode in result?

for small records maybe this algorithm work but i guess when table grown up maybe it works so slow because every time it need return all tags as separated records.


For dynamicity you build the respective SQL passing values (that are fixed in the example such as q200) as bound parameters (typically an ? for a parameter) see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam, binding parameters protects against SQL Injection. As for inefficiency, that is inherent with the choice to store delimited lists instead of utilising the relational aspect of the database, the pcode part of the WHERE clause could be applied to cte_split.
